# Add Marcador com click

Tags: android, google-maps

Como faço para adicionar um marcador no mapa com um click?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


       // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap;

      // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
       LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do método `onMapRead` basta usar o método `setOnMapClickListener()` incluindo as configurações do `Marker`, passando latitude e longitude. Veja:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // define latitude longitude e titulo do marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");
        // inclui um marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);

    }
});
```